# Fatal error: Uncaught exception .. using php SwiftMailer

Tags: php, swiftmailer

I am using SwiftMailer for sending mails and if I try to use dummy email address, for example if I type in "asdf" in email address, I get this uncaught exception.

```
   Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Swift_RfcComplianceException' with message 
'Address in mailbox given [asdf] does not comply with RFC 2822,
```

I am not very experienced in OO .. so not sure how to handle this? Actually I just want it to fail if the email address is not valid but it shouldnt throw the fatal error message. Any suggestions?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to catch the exception, like this

```
try
{
    // Your code to send the email
}
catch (Swift_RfcComplianceException $e)
{
    print('Email address not valid:' . $e->getMessage());
}
```

This isn't an OO thing, it's an [exceptions](http://php.net/exception) thing.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can validate the email before sending it:

```
if(!Swift_Validate::email($email)){ //if email is not valid
                //do something, skip them
                $log_error->log($email);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that it means that the given email address doesn't respect the email adressess standards.

Answer (score 0):

If the email address is valid based on what you see in the error message, make sure that there are no leading or trailing spaces in the address. eg. run trim($email_address).